# Python3: DCOM в Thread

Tags: python, многопоточность

Здравия. Как корректно вызвать DCOM в потоке?

Сейчас при обращении в **init** всё нормально, но в run() выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\TMCoords\2t.py", line 71, in run
    TMMgr = win32com.client.Dispatch("TMMgr.TMManager")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in
Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,c
lsctx)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in
_GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _
GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.II
D_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'Не был произведен вызов CoInitialize.', Non
e, None)
```

Comment: хм... а ошибка где?

Comment: @BOPOH, жмякнул случайно отправить до того как установил PyQT, писал на другом компе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Три часа гугла и капля интуиции решили проблему.

```
import pythoncom
#Сразу перед инициализацией DCOM в run()
pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(0)
```